# Showing 'E' in jest test coverage report

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am working in `jest` environment and when looking for `test coverage` its showing in one line uncover with symbol `E`, what is that ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, `E` stands for `else path not taken`, which means that for the marked if/else statement, the `if` path has been tested but not the `else`.